# Why facebook fql query is showing blank result?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get like_info of a post in graph explorer by FQL.Like_info/Comment_info/Share_info whatever i query the result is empty.See the image.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9AFKCiUY98WRnhORVFFOVltNEU/edit

Have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the `stream` table then? Please add some FQL query code so that we can follow what you are trying to achieve!

Notice that you need the read_stream permission with the appropriate access token for the respective User/Page as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/#permissions

Comment: Yes, i am using stream table.The query is (select like_info from stream where post_id=10202301160640775) .can you tell me how to get the permission in graph explorer?

Comment: In the Graph Explorer click on the "Get Access Token" button, and navigate to "Extended Permissions". There you can select the "read_stream" permission. Are you sure the object ID you're trying to query is a Post?

Comment: Actually this is my profile picture.I think it is a post,isn't it?If not then how can i query user photos?

Comment: A profile picture isn't a post! Where have you got the id from?

Comment: You should really read the basics of the FB Graph API before posting broad questions. Start here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/ and here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album/

Comment: i have got the id from this link-https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10202301160640775 .

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums with "user_photos" permission. Use the id of each result to access the album photos. It's all in the docs.

Comment: That helped me a lot.In your profile there is no contact info.If you don't mind can you give me your contact mail or please mail me at mahbuba2099@gmail.com .I have something to discuss with you.Thank you

Comment: Hello,mr.tobi where are you?